# node specific locks on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have around three Jenkins slave that are configured to run the same job allowing only one concurrent run on each slave. Each of these slave is connected to an embedded hardware that we run the job on. The total duration of the job is around 2 hours. The first 1 hour 50 mins is just taken to compile and configure the slave and the last 10 mins is when the embedded device is used. So basically I was looking for something that I can lock on for the last 10 mins. This would allow us to run multiple concurrent builds on the same slave. 
Locks and Latches locks are shared across nodes. 
What I am looking for is a node specific lock

Comment: It's more easy to configure the compile job as a single job and a single job for your other task on embedded device. You can trigger the second one after the first one is done (Add postbuild step -> build other projects). If you don't want to seperate I have no idea about any plugin that could help you.. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you can separate the problematic section from the compilation process you can just create another job to handle the last 10 minutes and call it using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). This job will run one instance at a time and will act as a native blocker for the run. That way, you can configure concurrent executions and throttling (if needed) on the main job, and create a "gate" to the problematic section.